# Browser detection - checkbox change events

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, events, browser-feature-detection

I'm creating a form with some fancy interactivity which depends on the change event of radio buttons. As ie doesn't trigger this event until another element is focused I need to branch my code, but want to go down the feature detection rather than browser detection route.

Looking at a few resources (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/, http://kangax.github.com/cft/) I can't find any implementation of detecting ie's buggy radio/checkbox change events.

Does anyone know how I might be able to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, [click](http://api.jquery.com/click) and [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) are the only event to trust in this case.

```
(function () {
  $('#yourRadio').bind('click keyup', function () {
    // check value with $(this).val()
  });
}());
```

Comment: Indeed, to detect change store the last selected button in some global context then in the click/keyup events check if the source element is different which means it's the new selected button.

Comment: I had to alter this slightly as my form hides teh input so the click is on my <label> tags, but otherwise this works well.